# How to add print styles for a CSS bundle?

Tags: css, media, bundles, print-style

I am currently have a site, where all of our CSS files, is being bundled into one file.  Problem now is, there is a need to want to add print style for this site, but how do i go about this?

All CSS files is currently included in the main css bundle, meaning that all styles are imported from that one.

I don't wan't make a new CSS bundle for print styles only, is there any way i can include a printstyles in my main css bundle,

And only use that style, when page is being previewed for print?

Comment: `@media print { YOUR PRINT CSS }`

Comment: Where would you scope/add this
in a separate CSS file, and then include it in the main CSS bundle, 
If so, will that be enough to add print styles ?

Comment: Add it at the end of your CSS file since you want to overwrite the defaults.

Comment: for the main bundle, or each individual?, The main bundle is being compiled/build together, so I would have to inject that pipeline.. No way I can add a css file with the `@media print{}` in a separate Css file, include in the main css bundle, and have it compiled ?

Comment: I've no idea since I know nothing about your bundling process. Just treat it like any other CSS in your project.

Comment: what about how it is included in the html..

Right now it is added as 
`<link href="some_path" type="text/css">` there is no media defined here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same CSS you can target print layouts with a media query

```
@media print {
  .snig { 
     display: none;
   }
}
```